# Python hangman code

Tags: python, python-3.x, hangman

guys I'm new to python and I decided to learn it via doing some project myself so I started working on Hangman game is there somebody willing to chceck my code for some common mistakes and what could be better done than it is, btw the works fine.

```
import random


def rand_word(version):
    if version.lower() == "slovak":
        words = open("Slova", "r")
        all_lines = words.readlines()
        line_num = random.randint(0, len(all_lines))
        words.close()
        return all_lines[line_num]
    elif version.lower() == "english":
        words = open("Words", "r")
        all_lines = words.readlines()
        line_num = random.randint(0, len(all_lines))
        words.close()
        return all_lines[line_num]
    else:
        print("Wrong input! [FATAL ERROR]")
        input("Press enter to EXIT!")
        exit()


def draw(what_to_do):

    HANGMANPICS = ['''
      +---+
      |   |
          |
          |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''
      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
          |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''
      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
      |   |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''
      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
     /|   |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''
      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
     /|\  |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''
      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
     /|\  |
     /    |
          |
    =========''', '''
      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
     /|\  |
     / \  |
          |
    =========''']

    if what_to_do == 1:
        print(HANGMANPICS[what_to_do])
    elif what_to_do == 2:
        print(HANGMANPICS[what_to_do])
    elif what_to_do == 3:
        print(HANGMANPICS[what_to_do])
    elif what_to_do == 4:
        print(HANGMANPICS[what_to_do])
    elif what_to_do == 5:
        print(HANGMANPICS[what_to_do])
    elif what_to_do == 6:
        print(HANGMANPICS[what_to_do])
    elif what_to_do == 7:
        print(HANGMANPICS[what_to_do])
    else:
        print(HANGMANPICS[0])


def list_fill(size):
    i = 0
    size -= 1
    while i < size:
        positions.append("_")
        i += 1


print("HANGMAN")
print("You have 6 tries to guess the correct word!")
dictionary = input("Chose dictionary Slovak or English: ")
positions = []
tries = 0
win_con = 1
addition = False
temp_word = rand_word(dictionary)
#print(temp_word)
list_fill(len(temp_word))


while tries < 6:

    counter = 0
    draw(tries)
    print(*positions)
    user_letter = input("Enter a letter: ")

    for letter in temp_word:

        if letter == user_letter:
            positions[counter] = letter
            win_con += 1
            tries -= 1
        else:
            addition = True

        counter += 1

    if addition:
        tries += 1

    if win_con == len(temp_word):
        print("You have won!")
        print(*positions)
        input("Press enter to EXIT!")
        exit()

print("You have run out of tries! ")
print(f"The word was {temp_word.upper()}")
input("Press enter to EXIT!")
```

Comment: `version = version.lower()` and you don't have to repeate `lower()` in all `if/else`

Comment: BTW: `HANGMANPICS` has elements with indexes from 0 to 6 but you use index 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below my version with changes - I didn't run it to test.

I describe it after code.

```
import random

# --- constants ---

HANGMANPICS = ['''
      +---+
      |   |
          |
          |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''
      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
          |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''
      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
      |   |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''
      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
     /|   |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''
      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
     /|\  |
          |
          |
    =========''', '''
      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
     /|\  |
     /    |
          |
    =========''', '''
      +---+
      |   |
      O   |
     /|\  |
     / \  |
          |
    ========='''
]

# --- functions ---

def rand_word(version):
    
    version = version.lower()
    
    if version == "slovak":
        filename = "Slova"
    elif version == "english":
        filename = "Words"
    else:
        print("Wrong input! [FATAL ERROR]")
        input("Press enter to EXIT!")
        exit()

    words = open(filename) 
    #all_lines = words.readlines()  # it keeps `\n` in lines
    #all_lines = words.read().split('\n')  # it removes `\n`  in lines
    all_lines = words.read().splitlines()  # it removes `\n`  in lines
    words.close()
    
    print(all_lines)

    #line_num = random.randint(0, len(all_lines))
    #return all_lines[line_num]

    word = random.choice(all_lines)
    return word    

def draw(what_to_do):

    if 1 <= what_to_do <= 7:
        print(HANGMANPICS[what_to_do])
    else:
        print(HANGMANPICS[0])
   
    # or

    #if what_to_do < 1 or what_to_do > 7:
    #    what_to_do = 0
    #print(HANGMANPICS[what_to_do])

def list_fill(size):
    return ["_"] * size
    #return ["_"] * size-1 # if you didn't remove `\n` from lines

# --- main ---
print("HANGMAN")
print("You have 6 tries to guess the correct word!")

dictionary = input("Chose dictionary Slovak or English: ")

tries = 0
win_con = 0

temp_word = rand_word(dictionary)
positions = list_fill(len(temp_word))

while tries < 6:

    counter = 0
    
    draw(tries)
    #print(*positions)
    print(' '.join(positions))  # the same result
    
    user_letter = input("Enter a letter: ")

    addition = False
    
    for letter in temp_word:

        if letter == user_letter:
            positions[counter] = letter
            win_con += 1
            tries -= 1
        else:
            addition = True

        counter += 1

    if addition:
        tries += 1

    if win_con == len(temp_word):
        print("You have won!")
        print(*positions)
        input("Press enter to EXIT!")
        exit()

print("You have run out of tries! ")
print(f"The word was {temp_word.upper()}")
input("Press enter to EXIT!")
```

---

**rand_word()**

You could convert to lower only once

```
version = version.lower()
```

Inside `if/else` you use the same code so you could use it after `if/else`

```
if version == "slovak":
    filename = "Slova"
elif version == "english":
    filename = "Words"
else:
    print("Wrong input! [FATAL ERROR]")
    input("Press enter to EXIT!")
    exit()

words = open(filename) 
all_lines = words.readlines()  # it keeps `\n` in lines
words.close()

line_num = random.randint(0, len(all_lines))
return all_lines[line_num]
```

But `readlines()` gives lines with `\n` (and probabably later you have to use `size-1` and `win_con = 1`) but you can read it in different way to remove the `\n`

```
all_lines = words.read().split('\n')  # it removes `\n`  in lines
```

or

```
all_lines = words.read().splitlines()  # it removes `\n`  in lines
```

Eventually use list compression to remove `\n` from elements on list

```
all_lines = [line.strip() for line in all_lines]
```

Using`strip()` or `rstrip()` it removes also spaces/tabs if they are in file.

`random` has many useful functions and you can get random word without using index

```
word = random.choice(all_lines)

return word
```

BTW: There can be one problem - if would run hangmap for many words then `choice()` (or `randint()`) may select the same word again. You would have to remeber which word was already used and repeat selection - or you should shuffle list `random.shuffle(all_lines)` and later you can run code with `for word in all_lines` and it will use different words in random order.

---

**draw()**

`HANGMANPICS` never changes so it is good that you use `UPPER_CASE_NAME`. But you could put it outside function. Inside function it will create it again and again when you run `draw()` (but it has always the same values so there is no need to create again and again)

**EDIT:** `HANGMANPICS` has elements with indexes from `0` to `6` but you use `7`

You can use `<=` instead of `==` to make it simpler

```
if 1 <= what_to_do <= 6:  # EDIT: it has to be 6 instead of 7
    print(HANGMANPICS[what_to_do])
else:
    print(HANGMANPICS[0])
```

or use "reversed" comparitions

```
if what_to_do < 1 or what_to_do > 6:  # EDIT: it has to be 6 instead of 7
    what_to_do = 0

print(HANGMANPICS[what_to_do])
```

---

**list_fill()**

You can use `*` to repeat strings on list.

```
def list_fill(size):
    return ["_"] * size-1
```

And use `return` to assign to `position`

```
positions = list_fill(len(temp_word))
```

This way you can run it in a loop which repeats the game with next word

---

**other code**

I'm not sure but `addition = False` probably should be inside `while`-loop before every `for`-loop which change `addition = True`

---

**BTW:** `open()` as default use `"r"` so you don't have to use it.

---

**EDIT:** I don't know if I understand `addition`. You add only 1 to `tries` when you don't guess letter but you also subract from `tries` many times - ie. if you guess `a` in word `ABBA` then it substracts 2 because `a` is two times in this word. The same for char `b` - it substracts 2. This way you can get tries smaller then `0`

I would use to add 1 only when not found letter - and keep current value when found letter (and it doesn't matter how many times it exists in word).

```
    found = False
    
    for index, letter in enumerate(word):
        if letter == user_letter:
            positions[index] = letter
            win_con += 1
            found = True

    if not found:
        tries += 1
```

Comment: I never like the "wrong input => abandon ship" approach. Just give the user a chance to correct himself without needing to restart the program.

Comment: @infinitezero you can describe it with code as answer and it will be useful for OP and other users.